# Solving a linear program with simplex algorithm, matrix not full rank

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have that matrix named A:

\begin{bmatrix}   1 & 3  &1&0&0 \\   -2&-2&0&1&0 \\ 2&4&0&0&1     \end{bmatrix}

I need to solve the LP : $$ \min: -x_1 - x_2$$ and $$Ax = ( 2,2,4)^T$$

This matrix is not full rank. Then the only way to solve that problem is to create an equivalent problem with a full rank matrix ? Here for instance :

$$ \min \{ (c,-c) (x^+,x^-)^T : \begin{bmatrix}   A & -A \\   -I& 0 \\ 0& -I \end{bmatrix}   (x^+,x^-)^T \leq (b, 0,0)^T \} $$

but I don't know how to solve a problem with $x^+$ and $x^-$. Would you have an example ?

> So my question is how to solve such a problem, and if you'd recommand
>   my method, how do you use it, especially concerning the $x^+$ part.

I've asked that question on computer sciences also, but i was unsure if it is a computer science or math question. (cf https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111189/solving-a-linear-program-with-simplex-algorithm-matrix-not-full-rank)

Comment: The matrix $A$ is full rank, which makes the Question you asked difficult to interpret.

Comment: You can do the simplex on it??? I used as a basis 3,4,5 and got a lambda = 0. Seemed to me it s a feasible basis. But then I recall it s not how simplex works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do the simplex algorithm on it.  After splitting your variables into their non-positive and non-negative parts, you get the following simplex tableau:
 \begin{array}{cccccccccc|c}
   \fbox{1} & 3  &1&0&0&-1&-3&-1&0&0&2\\   -2&-2&0&1&0&2&2&0&-1&0&2\\
 2&4&0&0&1&-2&-4&0&0&-1&4\\
\hline
-1&-1&0&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0
\end{array}
This is in feasible canonical form with basic variables $\ x_3^+,x_4^+\ $ and $\ x_5^+\ $, so you're right about that.  However, since there are negative entries in the objective row, you know the basic solution is not optimal.  To proceed with the simplex algorithm You can choose to pivot on either first or second columns, and an appropriate row. If you choose the first row and first column, the new tableau is:
 \begin{array}{cccccccccc|c}
   1 & 3  &1&0&0&-1&-3&-1&0&0&2\\   0&4&2&1&0&0&-4&-2&-1&0&6\\
 0&-2&-2&0&1&0&\fbox{2}&2&0&-1&0\\
\hline
0&2&1&0&0&0&-2&-1&0&0&2
\end{array}
Now pivoting on the third row and seventh column gives the following tableau:
 \begin{array}{cccccccccc|c}
   1 & 0 &-2&0&\frac{3}{2}&-1&0&2&0&-\frac{3}{2}&2\\   0&0&-2&1&2&0&0&2&-1&-2&6\\
 0&-1&-1&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&1&1&0&-\frac{1}{2}&0\\
\hline
0&0&-1&0&1&0&0&1&0&-1&2
\end{array}
Since all the entries in the tenth column in this tableau are negative, this tells you that there are feasible solutions which can make the objective arbitrarily small. Indeed if you take $\ x_5^-\ $ to be the only non-basic variable with a non-zero value, the tableau tells you that the following values for the basic variables
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1^+&=& 2+\frac{3x_5^-}{2}\\
x_4^+&=& 6+2x_5^-\\
x_2^-&=&\frac{x_5^-}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
will give you a feasible solution for *any* value of $\ x_5^-\ $.  But the objective has value $\ -x_1^+ + x_2^- = -2-x_5^- \ $, which can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $\ x_5^-\ $ sufficiently large.

In terms of the original variables, what this says is that $\ x_1=2-\frac{3x_5}{2}\ $,  $\ x_2=\frac{x_5}{2}\ $,  $\ x_3=0\ $, and $\ x_4=6-2x_5\ $ is a feasible solution for any value of $\ x_5\ $, which can easily be checked by substituting these values into the equation
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
  1& 3  &1&0&0\\
-2&-2&0&1&0\\
 2&4&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4\\
x_5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\4\end{bmatrix}\ ,$$
and the objective $-x_1-x_2 = -2 + x_5\ $ can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $\ x_5\ $ sufficiently small.

**Explanation of edit:** The discussion below—in particular the fact that shadow prices should be non-negative—alerted me to the fact that I had originally used the reverse of the usual convention for the signs of the entries in the objective row.  While this did not affect the correctness of the solution, it could nevertheless have been confusing to anyone not fully aware of what equations are represented by the tableau.  I have therefore now reversed all the signs of that row, and of the conditions required for optimality, so that the procedure now follows the more standard convention.

Comment: Oh so you can do it with the tableau? Heard about that method but never studied it. So using the classic LP solving with lambda isn't working really well?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what "lambda" means.  When I learnt linear programming some 50 years ago it wasn't a term that seemed current as something that everyone ought to know the meaning of.   Nevertheless, if the "lambda" method is just another way of doing the simplex algorithm, then it should be equivalent to performing the algorithm with tableaux.

Comment: I think the lambda designed the reduce costs. Would it make sense? Thought in my lecture we never used that word. But i think i got the idea thank you.

Comment: If I remember correctly, $\ \lambda\ $ *was* quite commonly used as a symbol to represent the quantities known as *simplex multipliers*, or *shadow prices* for an optimal tableau.  When your initial tableau contains an identity matrix, and zeroes in the corresponding columns of the objective row, the quantities that appear in those columns of the objective row as the algorithm proceeds are called "simplex multipliers".  The simplex multipliers in an optimal tableau are also called "shadow prices".